# What is wrong with the if/else code in Java? its not working

Tags: java, android, if-statement, control-flow

I'm trying to programme in android, but my if/else code is not working. Basically, its a quiz application that determines whether a person's answers are correct or not. But whatever the answer, the output is the output given in 'else'.

```
if(message=="panama canal"){
         Answer="Correct!";
    }
    else {
        Answer="Totally wrong";

    }
```

Comment: String comparision with equals() method..change like if(message.equals("panama canal"){

Comment: `if(message=="panama canal"){` is **wrong**. Use `if(message.equals("panama canal")){`

Comment: Java's == operator check by reference, not by value (as .Net does) so  the reference to the "panama canal" string constant is always different to any string you declare at runtime

Answer (score 0):

In Java you need to compare Strings with the `equals` method. As written you are comparing if the two are the same object.

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment, rather than as an answer.